# Cannot understand the meaning of two lines in C

Tags: c

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173442/reading-each-line-of-file-into-array/19174415#19174415) program reads a text file into a string array, line by line. I can't understand the meaning of two lines in the code:

```
char **words = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*)*lines_allocated);

...

words = (char **)realloc(words,sizeof(char*)*new_size);
...
```

Please could you help me understand them?

Comment: Refer to the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) for `malloc` and `realloc`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
char **words = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char*)*lines_allocated);
```

Allocates `lines_allocated` pointers. When you use **pointer to pointers** you need to allocate space for the pointers, and them for each of those pointers you allocate space for you data, in this case, a `char *`.

```
words = (char **)realloc(words,sizeof(char*)*new_size);
```

This changes the size of the buffer, as the number of lines is unknown before you read the file, then you need to increase the number of pointers you allocate.

`words` points to a block that will store `lines_allocated` pointers at first moment and then it will be increased to `new_size` when needed.

In your code you also have a line like this:

```
/* Allocate space for the next line */
words[i] = malloc(max_line_len);
```

Which will allocate each string separately.

---

Also, don't cast the result of malloc:

- [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: If you're compiling your code as C++, then you have to cast the result of `malloc`, but if you're writing C++, you shouldn't use `malloc` in the first place.

Comment: @JohnBode I know, but he tagged as C.

Answer (score 4):

The first line allocates a pointer to a pointer to character. A pointer to something in C is equivalent to a pointer to an array of that same something, so this is equivalent to saying that it allocates a pointer to an array of pointers to char.

`sizeof(char*)` is the size of a pointer, and multiplying it by `lines_allocated` means that the number of pointers in the allocated array will be `lines_allocated`.

The second line reallocates the array of pointers so that it may now contain `new_size` pointers instead of `lines_allocated` pointers.  If `new_size` is larger, the new pointers will be undefined, and must be initialized before being used.

Answer (score 4):

The first line allocates a chunk of dynamic memory (creates space for an array of pointers to `char`); the second line resizes that chunk.

A better way to write both lines is

```
char **words = malloc( sizeof *words * lines_allocated); // no cast, operand of sizeof

char **tmp = realloc( words, sizeof *words * new_size );
if ( tmp )
  words = tmp;
```

In C, you don't need to cast the result of either call, and it's considered bad practice to do so.  Also, note the operand to `sizeof`; if you ever change the base type of `words` (from `char` to `wchar_t`, for example), you won't have to change the `malloc` or `realloc` calls.

`realloc` will return `NULL` if it can't extend the buffer, so it's safer to assign the result to a temporary variable first, otherwise you risk losing your reference to that memory, meaning you won't be able to access or release it.